# Google cloud platform not enough resources available [to start instance]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, resources, google-compute-engine

Pre configured instances cannot be started in London Zone.  Instances that started two days ago are fine.  Google dashboard shows all is fine.  Is there any other status dashboard that shows if new instances are not available?  Saying "all is fine" is not the whole picture.

It makes relying on GCP very uncertain if one cannot bring up and down servers on a scheduled basis.  Moving zones is not an option due to data protection issues stipulated by my client.

Changed sub-zone region eg europe-west-a; europe-west-b; europe-west-c.
Five hours no change - not good enough for an automated system we run.

Starting VM instance "[xxx]" failed. Error: The zone 'projects/[xxx]/zones/europe-west2-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

Comment: Do you have custom vpc? how many cpu/gpu are you using? what type of vm would you want to add?

Comment: Just looking for a bog standard N1 instance.might be completely unrelated but if you were to look at the pricing page https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing and select a non-Iowa, or singapore region it says "not available" but we know Frankfurt is available so may just be a bug on that website.

Comment: You can perform `gcloud compute regions list` to view resources available for your project.